# Right angle list in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, view, angle

How do you make a right angle list using `List` in SwiftUI?
As you see in the image shown below, I add a `.stroke()` modifier for each row of the list, but the corners are clipped by the `List`.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0){
            Text("this is a text")
            Spacer()
            List {
                ForEach(1..<5) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text("item\(item)")
                            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
                    }
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    .frame(height:50)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2))
                }
            }
            .frame(height : 500)
            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: What you mean by "right angle list" is far from clear. Please edit your question to better describe what you're talking about. Are you just looking for square corners on the list?

Comment: I am sorry for poor expression. yes , i just want square corners on the list. since I have known how to make a square corners without List View, now I just try to realize same functions inside List view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RoundedRectangle()`. Here is how to use it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0){
            Text("this is a text")
            Spacer()
            List {
                ForEach(1..<5) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text("item\(item)")
                            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
                    }
                    .frame(height:40)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 11).stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2))
                }
            }
            .frame(height : 500)
            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
        }
    }
}
```

I modified the frame to fit the overlay a little bit better. Here is how it looks:

[image: List]

And what are you meaning with right angled list?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question. I just follow requirements from my  client. one of which is to show a list with square angle. without using List view. like ForEeach, I have implemented same functions. now I just try same thing done inside List view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add the `.listStyle(.grouped)` line just below the `.scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))` line to get the result like this:

[image]